# Julia not returning the same value when executing a function or every of its lines

Tags: julia, juno-ide

I am a very new Julia user (coming from Matlab), so forgive me if I ask a very dumb question.

I currently have a julia code, which works (it runs fine) though it provides different results if I execute it as a function or if I run every of the function lines interactively.
My script is mostly about linear algebra and uses Arrays and Dicts.

As I have some trouble making use of the Juno debugger, I did not find another way to debug my code, which is quite a shame.

I spent the last three hours on this and I still have no clue why these results differ.
I suspect I don't understand some very basic working process of julia related to variable allocation but I'm flying blind here.

Does anyone have a explaination for this behavior ?

I can't provide the code here but here is the base structure of the code. Basically the `M` matrix returned by `childfunction` is wrong. `a` is a scalar a `dict` is a dictionary.

- calling function

```
function motherfunction(...)
    M = childfunction(a,dict)
end
```

- child function

```
function childfunction(...)
...
    M = *some linear algebra*
return M
end
```

Comment: Most likely you have some global variables that change behavior when running outside of a function. the way you use code in the question is correct.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel Could you explain what you mean by *that change behavior* ?

Comment: You said "provides different results if I execute it as a function or if I run every of the function lines interactively". Perhaps you run your code line by line in a console. The problem is that variable scoping has different rules in the console and in a function. Please read https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/   I am not able to say anything more because you would need to add some simple illustrative example to your question

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel, I read some stuff about variable scoping in julia, and I was quite surprised compared to matlab. I do not use any global variable, if that makes any difference. I will try to provide a MWE as soon as I can. I wonder if the new function definition was updated, is there a way to ensure the function code is recompiled or is it performed after each function file modification ? This may explain why I hav different results between function and script mode, wouldn't it ?

Comment: Another very useful reading in your case: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/noteworthy-differences/     You might have indeed two functions definitions (I do not know what you actully did without MWE)

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel, thanks for the info. I already read this, yet I may not have understood all the peculiarities of julia. Would you have a tip for a correct debugging process, juno seems quite unresponsive for that (also read stuff about this, but nothing very useful so far, even on the julia official site)

Comment: Juno is no longer supported as Julia dev platform - as of today you have to use MS VS Code

Comment: You could also put your function within a module and then use Revise.jl and `import` or `using` your module in a "calling" script or console. Then everytime you save the file with the function, the definition is updated.